# Cannot install C++ templates for Visual Studio 2017, error "Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.TargetingPack"?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Tried restarting and reinstalling, neither help. To clarify whether I'm modifying the Visual Studio installation, installing it from scratch or trying to install the separate C++ build with another installer, I  get this same error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: The error log I get]

Comment: 1. don't post screencaps, you could have easily posted that text.  2. there's mention of a logfile in that output - what's in there?  any hints as to what failed?

Comment: @Joe Here is the pastebin of that errorlog: https://pastebin.com/YD8CtmAY